# Get an Integer from Entry

Tags: python, tkinter

How do I get an integer type from the Tkinter `Entry` widget?

If I try to get the value using `variable_name.get()`, it says it is a `str`. If I try to change the type using `int(variable_name.get())`, it says int can only accept a string or number.

Any help would be welcome!

Comment: What is the value of the variable?

Comment: Are you able to see the value of str(variable.get())? Though this should be unnecessary, since v.get should return a string.

Comment: `int(variable.get())` should work if `variable` is a `StringVar`.  What do you get for `print repr(variable.get())` and also for `print type(variable.get())`?

Answer (score 4):

In the end I just initialized the variable as `tk.IntVar()` instead of `tk.StringVar()`

That way you don't have to cast it as an int, it will always be one, and the default value from the Entry element will now be `0` instead of `''`

That's how I approached it anyway, seems the simplest way and avoid the need for a lot of the validation you'd need to do otherwise...

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same problem recently. I had a small method running :

```
newSave = self.EntryDict[key].get
        try: 
            int(newSave)
            bool = True
        except ValueError:
            bool = False
```

And I got the error you are describing that It can only accept a string or a number. 
And my problem was that my .get didn't have the parenthesis. After I put .get() everything worked. I think this might be your problem too. But not seeing any of your code I can't know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

See the following example from Tkinter:

```
v = StringVar()
e = Entry(master, textvariable=v)
e.pack()

v.set("a default value")
s = v.get()
```

v is a StringVar class. try doing - int(str(variable.get()))

But the class says that variable.get should return you a string.

- http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/Tkinter.StringVar-class.html

Tkinter Entry has a default text value, that might be an issue if it is not integer data.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to Tkinter as well, and I also faced the same problem. I think the issue is that the default value of the Entry field is an empty string, which cannot be converted to integer.

I suggest you try adding an if statement to check for that case:

```
if variable.get() != '':
    other_variable = int(variable.get())
```

I understand that the question is old, but this worked for me and I thought I'd share.

Comment: This code is unsafe. You need to catch the possible @ValueError@ exception if the @int()@ conversion fails.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "variable" in your question, are you referring to an instance of a `StringVar` or a reference to the widget itself?

If you have a reference to the widget you can use the `get` method of the entry. This will return a string that you can then pass to the `int` function:

```
s = e.get()
i = int(s)
```

If this doesn't solve your problem can you provide some working code that shows exactly the problem you are having?

Answer (score 0):

```
int(str(variable.get()))
```

I try this and it works now.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you be a little more precise on why are you answering this question 6,5 years after it was asked and while it has been answered? Your answer will be interesting if it gives some fresh insight to the problem, e.g. when your solution is specific to a newer version of `TkInter`. Lastly, surround your code with backticks for visual reasons